# "Select All" in CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some working code, but I don't think it's the best way to achieve what I'm going for.

I have a CheckBoxList with 5 items - 4 individual items and 1 "Select All" item. When the Select All is selected, I want the other 4 to be checked off for the user. When the Select All is deselected, I want the other 4 to be unchecked for the user.

A bunch of things I've found on StackOverflow and Google simply suggest looping through CheckBoxList.Items, but this will not work for my case. For instance, say a user unchecked Item #3 - this would trigger the OnSelectedIndexChanged event, at which point I would begin looping through the Items. I would find that the "Select All" item is not selected, so I'd therefore deselect all items. Thus, a user would check off Item #3 only to have it be immediately deselected for them.

Below is my working code, but it uses some strange functions and I can't imagine that it's the best way to achieve what I'm looking for.

```
    protected void StatusCheckBoxListChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //Crazy code I found online to determine which item triggered the event
        CheckBoxList list = (CheckBoxList)sender;
        string[] control = Request.Form.Get("__EVENTTARGET").Split('$');
        int index = control.Length - 1;
        ListItem li = (ListItem)list.Items[Int32.Parse(control[index])];

        if (li.ToString().Equals("Select All")) //If it was the "Select All" Item which triggered the event
        {
            //If it was checked, check off everything. If it was unchecked, uncheck everything.
            for(int i = 0; i < StatusCheckBoxList.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                StatusCheckBoxList.Items[i].Selected = StatusCheckBoxList.Items.FindByValue("Select All").Selected;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you provide your markup for `CheckBoxList`?

Comment: Sure, although it is fairly standard. `<asp:CheckBoxList ID="StatusCheckBoxList" OnSelectedIndexChanged="StatusCheckBoxListChanged" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">`

Comment: it seems like better use yet another `CheckBox` instead of use item from `CheckBoxList`

Comment: Perhaps you're right, I just preferred the layout of having several items, one of which selects all other items. In any case, the question still remains whether there's a better way to get the most recently selected checkbox than the code I provided. It seems strange to me that that's the best option available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try add field to you page that was show previous value for *Select All* like this

```
bool SelectAll;
```

init it in `PageLoad` event handler, something like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostback){
        SelectAll = StatusCheckBoxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Text == "Select All" && d.Selected) != null;

    }
}
```

and change your event like this

```
protected void StatusCheckBoxListChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(SelectAll != (StatusCheckBoxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Text == "Select All" && d.Selected) != null)){
        SelectAll = !SelectAll;
        foreach(var li in StatusCheckBoxList.Items){
            li.Selected = SelectAll;
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** if you know position of item with "Select All" value you can do without LINQ something like this

**Sample for case when "Select All" is first item**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostback){
        SelectAll = StatusCheckBoxList.Items[0].Selected;
        foreach(var li in StatusCheckBoxList.Items){
            li.Selected = SelectAll;
        }
    }
}
```

and change your event like this

```
protected void StatusCheckBoxListChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(SelectAll != StatusCheckBoxList.Items[0].Selected){
        SelectAll = !SelectAll;
        foreach(var li in StatusCheckBoxList.Items){
            li.Selected = SelectAll;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does appear to be the best solution, and can be done without the 'crazy code' I provided, which, although working, is a bit of a hack. I much prefer your method! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've worked around this in the past by setting a flag e.g.

```
public class MyClass
{
    bool _IsReady = true;

    protected void StatusCheckBoxListChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_IsReady)
        {
            return;
        }

        //Crazy code I found online to determine which item triggered the event
        CheckBoxList list = (CheckBoxList)sender;
        string[] control = Request.Form.Get("__EVENTTARGET").Split('$');
        int index = control.Length - 1;
        ListItem li = (ListItem)list.Items[Int32.Parse(control[index])];

        if (li.ToString().Equals("Select All")) //If it was the "Select All" Item which triggered the event
        {
            SetAllStatusItemsSelected(StatusCheckBoxList.Items.FindByValue("Select All").Selected);
        }
    }


    private void SetAllStatusItemsSelected(bool IsSelected)
    {
        _IsReady = false;

        //If it was checked, check off everything. If it was unchecked, uncheck everything.
        for(int i = 0; i < StatusCheckBoxList.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            StatusCheckBoxList.Items[i].Selected = StatusCheckBoxList.Items.FindByValue("Select All").Selected;
        }

        _IsReady = true;
    }

}
```

I'd be interested to know if there is a more elegant way.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code - it loops through every Item and sets their Selected value to the same value as the "Select All" Item (regardless of whether the "Select All" item was the most recent one checked). Is that right?

Comment: it seems like `_IsReady` always `true` when you call `StatusCheckBoxListChanged`

Comment: Correct - but as soon as the logic to handle the "Select All" functionality is invoked and SetAllStatusItemsSelected() is called then the flag is set to false.  Thus, when each item is the CheckBoxList is reset, the OnSelectedIndexChanged event will be called but _IsReady will be false so the rest of the code in the handler will not run until all the items in the CheckBoxList are reset.

Comment: You said "I've worked around this in the past" but then included my "crazy code" in your answer - how does your code improve upon mine? (I don't mean to be accusatory, I'm honestly unsure)

Comment: Hmmm... it seems I missed the part where Jake said the code was working.  I may be trying to solve the wrong problem!  I hereby recind my answer - apologies all.

Comment: No problem at all. It works, but definitely needs improving. Thanks for trying! I really appreciate it

Comment: @Jake: no problem - will teach me to read in future!  I'm also surprised there isn't an easier way to do this but my searches hit the same solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655068/how-to-get-the-latest-selected-value-from-a-checkbox-list

Answer (score -1):

This the way I have always solved this issue

```
        protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBoxList lstBx = (CheckBoxList)sender;

        List<ListItem> list = lstBx.Items.Cast<ListItem>().ToList();
        string[] control = Request.Form.Get("__EVENTTARGET").Split('$');
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(control[control.Length - 1]);

        ListItem selectAllControl = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text == "Select All");
        ListItem selectAll = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Selected && x.Text == "Select All");

        if (index == 0)
        {               
            if (selectAll != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (selectAllControl != null)
            {
                selectAllControl.Selected = false;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: @Jake, What are you talking about unfortunate.?  This code works.

Comment: @LawrenceThurman, it seems you, like me, missed the start of both paragraph 1 and 4: "I have some working code..." and "Below is my working code...".  It works but it doesn't look elegant.

Comment: @MarkHone I did see the comments. This a lot cleaner code. One question to Jake- I do not see in your code where you unselect the select all when a user selects say your third item.

Comment: It's unfortunate because your code doesn't make any meaningful changes to mine. It includes what I labeled "crazy code" in order to find the most recently changed Item. You said that it's "a lot cleaner code", but mine is far fewer lines to achieve the same effect. As for "you unselect the select all when a user selects your third item", you're correct, I do not do that in the code I provided, nor do I select the select all should the user manually select every item. I do that in my personal code, but I didn't post it here as it's not really the question.

Comment: @Jake  one thing that you solution and mine solution allow a developer to do is reuse the code for all checkboxList controls. where if you use the flag method, you will need a flag for every checkboxlist control on your page.  Although you may only have one, and for this case you are good.