# Check only one checkbox at a time using checkboxlist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkboxlist

---

i have a `dropdownlist` of `employees types` `( Project Manager, developer , qa` etc ). and a checkboxList of tasks that need to be assigned to each employee type.
 but for developer , there will be only one task at a time. i.e a person will be able to assign only one task to a developer at a time. if he selects a second one, the first choice  should be unchecked. for other employees with multiple tasks , its working fine. but how to put a check in developer case ?

i have used below code but it is creating problem on edit , update. also when i select one task for a developer , all other checkbox get disabled and i cannot change the task.

```
 If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim developer As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Rows(0)(0).ToString())
        If developer Then
            For Each li As ListItem In cblTaskType.Items
                If Not li.Value = employeeType Then
                    li.Selected = False
                    li.Enabled = False
                End If

            Next
```

Comment: Any code  to share with us ?

Comment: You can do this by Client side code using Javascript or JQuery.

Comment: thanks @Selva but I want to do this in VB.net .

Comment: well this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655068/how-to-get-the-latest-selected-value-from-a-checkbox-list worked for me . thanks to everyone

Answer (score 2):

you can use below code ..
Use SelectedIndexChanged event of checkedListBox1 .

```
private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               int iSelectedIndex = checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex;
               if (iSelectedIndex == -1)
                   return;
               for (int iIndex = 0; iIndex < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; iIndex++)
                   checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(iIndex, CheckState.Unchecked);
               checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(iSelectedIndex, CheckState.Checked);
           }
```

you can also refer this [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/713589/how-to-check-only-one-checkbox-from-checkboxlist-i)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... I changed it to a radiobutton list and joined all the radio buttons to the same group (in properties).