# How to get the last selected index or value of checkboxlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using one checkboxlist where i have to check the last selected item index or value.Below is one example:

[image: Image here for your reference]

As we can see in this image orange, pineapple, watermelon is selected. when i used to get this selected item using foreach loop i want to get the last selected item index.

Comment: By last do you mean the last one selected in the list or the one which got selected at last?

Comment: Try using solution from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655068/how-to-get-the-latest-selected-value-from-a-checkbox-list.

Comment: Hi Tetsuya, I have gone through this link before and tested so what is happening it is checking selected item one by one not checking and confirm about which last item is selected in this list.

Answer (score 1):

As you didnt provided enough code , assuming that you already have the `selectedchangedIndex` method .

Try to update your SelectedChangedIndex As follows . This will give the Last selected value of checkboxlist

```
protected void yourcheckboxlistname_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value = string.Empty;

    string result = Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"];

    string[] checkedBox = result.Split('$'); ;

    int index = int.Parse(checkedBox[checkedBox.Length - 1]);

    if (yourcheckboxlistname.Items[index].Selected)
    {
        value = yourcheckboxlistname.Items[index].Value;
    }
    else
    {

    }


   // For getting the list of values that are selected u can get it like  
    //this
    int lastSelectedIndex = 0;
  string lastSelectedValue = string.Empty;

foreach (ListItem listitem in yourcheckboxlistname.Items)
{
    if (listitem.Selected)
    {
        int thisIndex = yourcheckboxlistname.Items.IndexOf(listitem);

        if (lastSelectedIndex < thisIndex)
        {
            lastSelectedIndex = thisIndex;
            lastSelectedValue = listitem.Value;
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi Webruster, As you know i am using checkboxlist. So according to this code for every checked item page will get refresh which i don't want. I want to put this logic in foreach loop only.

Comment: @PrityKumari you can avoid page reload by keeping the `Checkboxlist1` inside the `updatepanel`

Answer (score 0):

Do for loop then put the checked items on the string. The last string will give you the last item, then get its index. Assuming that your items are string in your CheckListBox:

```
string strGetLastItem = string.Empty;

       foreach (object item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            strGetLastItem = (string)item;
        }

       int index = checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(strGetLastItem);

//strGetLastItem will give you the last checked item.
//index will get the index of the item
```

Comment: Hi Willy, According to the given code it is running complete loop then after ending this loop checking the index. But my requirement is here in the loop only i should write the code to get which is the last item selected in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a List to hold the index of the item as its being checked. As an item gets checked, you add the index to the list. The last item checked will be the last index(int) in the list. This will let you know what was checked last.

```
var lastItemCheckedIndex = checkedItemsList.Count() - 1;
```

You also want to make sure that the logic that you write accounts for the scenario/event when the checkbox items are being unchecked. Every time an item is being unchecked you remove it from the list. If the last item on the list is removed then you will still be able to determine the last item that was checked prior.